# Why can't add UIView to UITableViewCell directly but contentView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I never think about this question before may be stupid.

```
[cell.contentView addsubview:xxxView];
```

and

```
[cell addsubview:xxxView];
```

Apple said `contentView` should be the default superview for contents. Just want to know if any bad if i add subviews to `cell` directly.

Apple document:

> The content view of a UITableViewCell object is the default superview for content displayed by the cell. If you want to customize cells by simply adding additional views, you should add them to the content view so they will be positioned appropriately as the cell transitions into and out of editing mode.

Comment: if you add subviews to cell it won't work for all UX
e.g. when you swipe for delete action that view will not move

Comment: Have you tried that? I tried it works smoothly.

Comment: I tried it is not working for me if I add that view in cell instead of contentView

Comment: OK let me try it again thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1

By default, the Editing Control is hidden until you enter edit mode for a table in which case, the Editing Control appears (the minus button left of each row) and your contentView gets resized and pushed to the right. This is probably what gives the "proper animation" effect.

To test the difference, try adding a subview such as UILabel with text, to the cell rather than the cell.contentView. When you add it to cell rather than cell.contentView and you enter edit mode for your table, I believe your UILabel will not resize, you will see the edit button ontop/below the minus sign button.